# Local path to my JSON works in notepad++ but will not load in the web page

Tags: javascript, json

This is a line that I have to load a local JSON file for development and testing purposes. The html file I am working on is in the same directory and is also local on the C drive. Notepad++ sees this as a file and automatically makes it a link. When I double click it, the file opens. However, in my web page, the json will not load. I cannot figure out why and I have tried multiple combinations of slashes. Any idea why it won't load? The page console shows no error

```
$.getJSON("file://C:/Users/ME/Desktop/Test/data.json", function(data) {
```

Thanks!
Also, is there a way to take out the "file://... and only leave the file name? I would like to send the folder I am working on to a friend and I don't want him to have to edit the link. Is there anything I can do?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Apart from "real" answers to your question, consider a domestic installation of Apache, restricted to local access. It'll make all these `file://` problems disappear.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, Chrome might be installed in your AppData folder:

> "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application"

Before you execute the command, make sure all of your Chrome window is closed and not otherwise running. Or, the command line param would not be effective.

> "chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files